# Where to subscribe findAllAsync().asObserable() without blocking the UI Thread?

Tags: android, multithreading, realm, rx-java

I want to use findAllAsync().asObservable() with realm. The realm object I use is a global instance created in application class. The problem is that the observable must subscribe on UI Thread becuase you can not move realm objects from one thread to another and the UI Thread gets blocked until findAllAsync is completed. So my question is how should I implement my realm logic and rx logic for solving this problem?

Comment: Realm is perfectly capable of querying reasonable amounts of data on UI thread as it is lazy accessed. If you need more information, please provide some code because it is not very clear what you want to achieve

Comment: What i want to achieve is reading from database using findAllAsync and then i want to update the UI with the result. I can use RealmChangeListener but using observable would be better. The problem is that if i use asObservable, the UI Thread gets blocked until findAllAsync is completed.

Comment: `findAllAsync` doesn't block UI thread. From doc - `Note that the query is not blocking and immediately returns a RealmResults<User>`

Comment: @Divers This is true but when I use asObservable, the observable is subscribed on UI Thread  and the UI Thread is blocked until findAllAsync() is completed. So the observable blocks the UI Thread.

Comment: `findAllAsync` will never being completed. And, no, UI thread will not be blocked. Please show your where you have experience problem.

Comment: `findAllAsync()` was created **exactly so that it is executed on Realm's own background thread**, which means if it "gets blocked until it is completed", then you have an error in your code, for example calling `realm.copyFromRealm()` or doing a `map()` operation on the entire list

Answer (score 0):

`findAllAsync()` does not get blocked. That's why it's called `async` in the first place.

However, if you obtain the result set and you start mapping the entire list, then you'll need to read every single element, which throws out lazy-loading.

```
Subscription subscription = realm.where(Blah.class) 
                              .findAllAsync()
                              .asObservable()
                              .filter(RealmResults::isLoaded)
                              //.map() <-- no map!
                              //.map(Realm::copyFromRealm) <-- NO copy from realm!
                              .subscribe(...);
```